# Getting IndexOutOfBoundsException while using CYaHPConverter.convertToPdf method

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

I am using `CYaHPConverter.convertToPdf` for converting HTML pages in my application to PDF. I have a specific scenario where there is a JSP which includes another sub JSP in it. While trying to convert from HTML to PDF I get the following error.

```
12:39:27,837 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10) Caused by: org.allcolor.yahp.converter.IHtmlToPdfTransformer$CConvertException: ERROR: An unhandled exc
eption occured: Index: 80, Size: 80
12:39:27,855 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.allcolor.yahp.cl.converter.CHtmlToPdfFlyingSaucerTransformer.transform(CHtmlToPdfFlyingSaucerT
ransformer.java:791)
12:39:27,875 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.allcolor.yahp.converter.CYaHPConverter.convertToPdf(CYaHPConverter.java:247)
12:39:27,885 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at com.wf.gib.compliance.service.PdfGenerationService.htmlToPdfFile(PdfGenerationService.java:57)
12:39:27,896 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   ... 60 more
12:39:27,907 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10) Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 80, Size: 80
12:39:27,916 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
12:39:27,926 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
12:39:27,937 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableSectionBox.cellAt(TableSectionBox.java:102)
12:39:27,947 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableRowBox.calcRowHeight(TableRowBox.java:346)
12:39:27,957 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableRowBox.calcLayoutHeight(TableRowBox.java:312)
12:39:27,967 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:829)
12:39:27,981 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableRowBox.layout(TableRowBox.java:88)
12:39:27,992 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:723)
12:39:28,007 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:255)
12:39:28,017 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:82)
12:39:28,027 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:914)
12:39:28,036 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableSectionBox.layoutChildren(TableSectionBox.java:136)
12:39:28,047 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:794)
12:39:28,056 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableSectionBox.layout(TableSectionBox.java:274)
12:39:28,066 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:723)
12:39:28,075 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:255)
12:39:28,086 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:82)
12:39:28,095 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:914)
12:39:28,105 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableBox.layoutChildren(TableBox.java:283)
12:39:28,115 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:794)
12:39:28,125 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:723)
12:39:28,133 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableBox.layoutTable(TableBox.java:249)
12:39:28,144 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.newtable.TableBox.layout(TableBox.java:227)
12:39:28,153 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:255)
12:39:28,163 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:82)
12:39:28,173 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:914)
12:39:28,183 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:794)
12:39:28,193 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:723)
12:39:28,202 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:255)
12:39:28,213 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:82)
12:39:28,223 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:914)
12:39:28,233 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:794)
12:39:28,244 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:723)
12:39:28,254 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:255)
12:39:28,265 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:82)
12:39:28,276 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:914)
12:39:28,286 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:794)
12:39:28,298 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:723)
12:39:28,307 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:255)
12:39:28,317 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:82)
12:39:28,327 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:914)
12:39:28,336 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:794)
12:39:28,347 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:723)
12:39:28,357 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:255)
12:39:28,372 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:82)
12:39:28,385 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:914)
12:39:28,396 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:794)
12:39:28,406 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:723)
12:39:28,415 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutBlockChild(BlockBoxing.java:255)
12:39:28,425 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.layout.BlockBoxing.layoutContent(BlockBoxing.java:82)
12:39:28,435 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layoutChildren(BlockBox.java:914)
12:39:28,444 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:794)
12:39:28,454 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.render.BlockBox.layout(BlockBox.java:723)
12:39:28,463 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.layout(ITextRenderer.java:154)
12:39:28,472 ERROR [stderr] (http--127.0.0.1-8080-10)   at org.allcolor.yahp.cl.converter.CHtmlToPdfFlyingSaucerTransformer.transform(CHtmlToPdfFlyingSaucerT
ransformer.java:766)
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because presumable bugs should probably be taken up with the creators of the library rather than us.

Comment: Hi , i resolved this issue, actually in the main jsp i had missed the </html> tag because of which this utility could not convert the jsp to pdf. i am facing another issue now the sub jsp's content is not gettign converted and added to pdf.